# Some programs are running but not opening in the window?

Tags: 14.04, command-line

I recently switched from windows to ubuntu.but everything seemed fine until I tried to open google-chrome which I downloaded from firefox and installed it via ubuntu gui package manager.but it doesn't who any window so i left clicked on the icon and it showed that new tab is running but it's not displayed on screen. so i also tried opening terminal and it also had the same problem and also same problem persisted with default text-editor app on ubuntu.i tried finding solution online but it didn't help. so is there any possible way to deal with this problem.

[image]

see the screenshot of the terminal icon in the menu (taskbar or whatever its called). In the screenshot you can clearly see that bash is opened in a like split screen window type. so maybe the problem is cant know how to switch between windows like this.so is this how ubuntu works or does ubuntu think that i'm using mulitple monitors?? sorry if this seems kinda nooby.thanks.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand your question. Programs open but don't run? You have a split screen?

Comment: There are a few options; 1. do you have a second monitor attached, but switched off? 2. You could have a non- existing second monitor (due to a bug). Open System settings > monitors. Could you post back what you see there?

Answer (score 4):

The solution was simple, I figured it out!

1. I went to System settings > Display.
2. There I found that I was having two unknown displays enabled so I simply turned off the second one.
3. Then I adjusted the needed resolution and in general options, I changed the launcher replacement to first unknown display, then I did the same for scale all windows to match setting.

Comment: Same thing happened to me.  Turning off the the other display show me the mess of windows that I had opened!